# MSO conditional in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, outlook, conditional-statements

i'm currently working on a react native project, and we have the problem with the emails that are read in outlook, the images take a different size respect to browsers.
so i partially found a solution, i mean , it works, but it could only be applied to the html/mail template , and in the react side `<!--[if gte mso 9]>` doesn't work, and most of the images came from react and not from the template.
so i wanted to know if theres a library, or a way to use that conditional or a similar one to apply on react

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to illustrate your question.

Comment: check an example of how it's been used in this MJML component https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/blob/master/packages/mjml-section/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for this, like so:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: '<!--[if gte mso]><b>this is outlook!<![endif]-->'}}></div>
```